# Dynamic routing with spring zuul

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul

We are using a zuul proxy for our microservices. We are looking for a way to add new microservices for different urls and ports without restarting/rebuilding zuul gateway. Our microservices are not using spring cloud and many are written in python and go. Is there any way to do this without setting up an additional spring config server because we will have to maintain another additional application?

Also, when the zuul application starts I saw a /routes mapping with GET and POST. I tried to POST new routes to it but that had no effect.

Comment: Zuul can quite easily use Eureka to discover available services. To have non java apps talk to eureka you can use the Netflix Sidecar project.

Comment: Do we have to create sidecar project for every non-jvm application?